Sql TRANSFORM with calculation time in MS Access
I'm Trying to make Sql TRANSFORM with calculation time in column in and out.
I want the answer in 1 query and I don't want to use the function in ms access because I want to use the sql in vb.net
Please Guide me
Thanks
Table ABSEN



DATE
TIME
INOUT
STATUS
LOCATION




26-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG


26-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG


27-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG


27-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG


28-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG


28-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG


29-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG


29-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG


30-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG


30-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG


31-Aug-24
08:20:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG


31-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG


01-Sep-24
0
IN
NOT PRESENT
BOJONG


01-Sep-24
0
OUT
NOT PRESENT
BOJONG



Table MASTERDAYS



LOCATION
DAY
DEFREST
DEFIN




BOJONG
Monday
01:00:00
08:00:00


BOJONG
Tuesday
01:00:00
08:00:00


BOJONG
Wednesday
01:00:00
08:00:00


BOJONG
Thursday
01:00:00
08:00:00


BOJONG
Friday
01:30:00
08:00:00


BOJONG
Saturday
01:00:00
08:00:00


BOJONG
Sunday
00:00:00
00:00:00



TRANSFORM Max(ABSEN.Time) AS MaxOfTIME
SELECT ABSEN.Date AS [DATE], 
       Format(ABSEN.Date,'dddd') AS DAYS, 
       ABSEN.STATUS AS STATUS, 
       IIF(ABSEN.STATUS = 'NOT PRESENT', '',MASTERDAYS.DEFREST) AS DEFREST
FROM ABSEN INNER JOIN MASTERDAYS AS MASTERDAYS ON (MASTERDAYS.DAY = FORMAT(ABSEN.DATE,'dddd')) AND (MASTERDAYS.LOCATION = ABSEN.LOCATION)
GROUP BY ABSEN.Date, 
         Format(ABSEN.Date,'dddd'), 
         ABSEN.STATUS, MASTERDAYS.DEFREST
PIVOT ABSEN.INOUT In ('IN','OUT');

Result From Code



DATE
DAYS
STATUS
DEFREST
IN
OUT




26-Aug-24
Monday
PRESENT
01:00:00
08:00:00
17:00:00


27-Aug-24
Tuesday
PRESENT
01:00:00
08:00:00
17:00:00


28-Aug-24
Wednesday
PRESENT
01:00:00
08:00:00
17:00:00


29-Aug-24
Thursday
PRESENT
01:00:00
08:00:00
17:00:00


30-Aug-24
Friday
PRESENT
01:30:00
08:00:00
17:00:00


31-Aug-24
Saturday
PRESENT
01:30:00
08:00:00
17:00:00


01-Sep-24
Sunday
NOT PRESENT

0
0



Desired output
DUROFWORK = (ABSEN.Time IN - ABSEN.Time OUT - MASTERDAYS.DEFREST)
LATEIN    = (ABSEN.Time IN - MASTERDAYS.DEFIN)
For status NOT PRESENT  I want to make blank for DEFREST,IN,OUT,DUROFWORK,LATEIN 



DATE
DAYS
STATUS
DEFREST
IN
OUT
DUROFWORK
LATEIN




26-Aug-24
Monday
PRESENT
01:00:00
08:00:00
17:00:00
08:00:00



27-Aug-24
Tuesday
PRESENT
01:00:00
08:00:00
17:00:00
08:00:00



28-Aug-24
Wednesday
PRESENT
01:00:00
08:00:00
17:00:00
08:00:00



29-Aug-24
Thursday
PRESENT
01:00:00
08:00:00
17:00:00
08:00:00



30-Aug-24
Friday
PRESENT
01:30:00
08:00:00
17:00:00
07:30:00



31-Aug-24
Saturday
PRESENT
01:30:00
08:00:00
17:00:00
06:10:00
00:20:00


01-Sep-24
Sunday
NOT PRESENT








Info data type 

Public Class DTOABSENTRANSFORMREPORT
    Public Property [DATE] As DateTime
    Public Property DAYS As String
    Public Property STATUS As String
    Public Property DEFREST As String
    Public Property TIME As String
    Public Property [IN] As String
    Public Property OUT As String
    Public Property DUROFWORK As String
    Public Property LATEIN As String
End Class


Update testing table as on 29-08-2024
Table ABSEN



ID
DATE
TIME
INOUT
STATUS
LOCATION
OPTION




1000
26-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG



1000
26-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG



1000
27-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG



1000
27-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG



1000
28-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG



1000
28-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG



1000
29-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG



1000
29-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG



1000
30-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG



1000
30-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG



1000
31-Aug-24
08:20:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG



1000
31-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG



1000
01-Sep-24
0
IN
NOT PRESENT
BOJONG



1000
01-Sep-24
0
OUT
NOT PRESENT
BOJONG



1001
26-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
26-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
27-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
27-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
28-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
28-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
29-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
29-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
30-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
30-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
31-Aug-24
08:20:00
IN
PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
31-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
01-Sep-24
0
IN
NOT PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
01-Sep-24
0
OUT
NOT PRESENT
OTHERS1



1001
01-Sep-24
0
OUT
NOT PRESENT
OTHERS1
NO


1002
26-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG



1002
26-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG



1002
27-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG



1002
27-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG



1002
28-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG



1002
28-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG



1002
29-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG



1002
29-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG



1002
30-Aug-24
08:00:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG



1002
30-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG



1002
31-Aug-24
08:20:00
IN
PRESENT
BOJONG



1002
31-Aug-24
17:00:00
OUT
PRESENT
BOJONG



1002
01-Sep-24
0
IN
NOT PRESENT
BOJONG



1002
01-Sep-24
0
OUT
NOT PRESENT
BOJONG




Table MASTERDAYS



LOCATION
DAY
DEFREST
DEFIN




BOJONG
Monday
01:00:00
08:00:00


BOJONG
Tuesday
01:00:00
08:00:00


BOJONG
Wednesday
01:00:00
08:00:00


BOJONG
Thursday
01:00:00
08:00:00


BOJONG
Friday
01:30:00
08:00:00


BOJONG
Saturday
01:00:00
08:00:00


BOJONG
Sunday
00:00:00
00:00:00


OTHERS1
Monday
01:00:00
07:00:00


OTHERS1
Tuesday
01:00:00
07:00:00


OTHERS1
Wednesday
01:00:00
07:00:00


OTHERS1
Thursday
01:00:00
07:00:00


OTHERS1
Friday
01:30:00
07:00:00


OTHERS1
Saturday
01:00:00
07:00:00


OTHERS1
Sunday
00:00:00
07:00:00



Table MASTERID



ID
NAMEID
LOCATION
POSITIONID




1000
A
BOJONG
STAFF


1001
B
OTHERS1
STAFF


1002
C
BOJONG
STAFF



SELECT 
    AIn.ID AS [ID]
 ,  AIn.Date AS [DATE]
  , MD.day AS [Day of Week]
  , MI.NAMEID
  , AIn.status
  , IIF(AIn.STATUS = 'NOT PRESENT', '',MD.DEFREST) AS DEFREST
  , IIF(AIn.STATUS = 'NOT PRESENT', '',AIn.TIME) AS [IN]
  , IIF(AIn.STATUS = 'NOT PRESENT', '',AOut.TIME) AS OUT
  , IIF(AIn.STATUS = 'NOT PRESENT', '',
          dateadd("s", datediff("s", AIn.TIME, AOut.TIME)-datediff("s", 0, MD.DefRest), 0)) AS DUROFWORK
  , IIF(cdate(AIn.[TIME]) > cdate(MD.DEFIN), format(dateadd("s", datediff("s", cdate(MD.DEFIN),
          cdate(AIn.[TIME])),0),"hh:nn:ss"),'') AS LATEIN
FROM ((ABSEN AS AIn 
       INNER JOIN MASTERDAYS AS MD ON AIn.LOCATION = MD.LOCATION) 
       INNER JOIN MASTERID AS MI ON MI.ID=AIn.ID)
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                  FROM ABSEN AS AOut1 
                  WHERE AOut1.INOUT='OUT') AS AOut ON (AOut.LOCATION=AIn.LOCATION) AND (AOut.DATE=AIn.DATE)
WHERE format(AIn.Date,"dddd")=MD.day
      AND  AIn.INOUT='IN' AND AIn.OPTION IS NULL AND AOut.OPTION IS NULL AND MI.POSITIONID='STAFF';


Result from code

Desired Result
  | ID   | DATE     | DAYS     | NAMEID   |  STATUS      |DEFREST  |IN       |OUT      |DUROFWORK|LATEIN   |
    | -----| -------- | -------- |  --------|  --------    |-------- |-------- |-------- |-------- |-------- |
    | 1000 | 26-Aug-24| Monday   | A        |   PRESENT    | 01:00:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 08:00:00|         |
    | 1000 | 27-Aug-24| Tuesday  | A        |   PRESENT    | 01:00:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 08:00:00|         |
    | 1000 | 28-Aug-24| Wednesday| A        |   PRESENT    | 01:00:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 08:00:00|         |
    | 1000 | 29-Aug-24| Thursday | A        |   PRESENT    | 01:00:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 08:00:00|         |
    | 1000 | 30-Aug-24| Friday   | A        |   PRESENT    | 01:30:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 07:30:00|         |
    | 1000 | 31-Aug-24| Saturday | A        |   PRESENT    | 01:30:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 06:10:00|00:20:00 |
    | 1000 | 01-Sep-24| Sunday   | A        |   NOT PRESENT|         |         |         |         |         |          
    | 1001 | 26-Aug-24| Monday   | B        |   PRESENT    | 01:00:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 08:00:00|01:00:00 |
    | 1001 | 27-Aug-24| Tuesday  | B        |   PRESENT    | 01:00:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 08:00:00|01:00:00 |
    | 1001 | 28-Aug-24| Wednesday| B        |   PRESENT    | 01:00:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 08:00:00|01:00:00 |
    | 1001 | 29-Aug-24| Thursday | B        |   PRESENT    | 01:00:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 08:00:00|01:00:00 |
    | 1001 | 30-Aug-24| Friday   | B        |   PRESENT    | 01:30:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 07:30:00|01:00:00 |
    | 1001 | 31-Aug-24| Saturday | B        |   PRESENT    | 01:30:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 06:10:00|00:20:00 |
    | 1001 | 01-Sep-24| Sunday   | B        |   NOT PRESENT|         |         |         |         |         |
    | 1002 | 26-Aug-24| Monday   | C        |   PRESENT    | 01:00:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 08:00:00|         |
    | 1002 | 27-Aug-24| Tuesday  | C        |   PRESENT    | 01:00:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 08:00:00|         |
    | 1002 | 28-Aug-24| Wednesday| C        |   PRESENT    | 01:00:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 08:00:00|         |
    | 1002 | 29-Aug-24| Thursday | C        |   PRESENT    | 01:00:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 08:00:00|         |
    | 1002 | 30-Aug-24| Friday   | C        |   PRESENT    | 01:30:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 07:30:00|         |
    | 1002 | 31-Aug-24| Saturday | C        |   PRESENT    | 01:30:00| 08:00:00| 17:00:00| 06:10:00|00:20:00 |
    | 1002 | 01-Sep-24| Sunday   | C        |   NOT PRESENT|         |         |         |         |         |              




Problem Solved AND (AOut.ID=AIn.ID)
SELECT 
    AIn.ID AS [ID]
 ,  AIn.Date AS [DATE]
  , MD.day AS [Day of Week]
  , MI.NAMEID
  , AIn.status
  , IIF(AIn.STATUS = 'NOT PRESENT', '',MD.DEFREST) AS DEFREST
  , IIF(AIn.STATUS = 'NOT PRESENT', '',AIn.TIME) AS [IN]
  , IIF(AIn.STATUS = 'NOT PRESENT', '',AOut.TIME) AS OUT
  , IIF(AIn.STATUS = 'NOT PRESENT', '',
          dateadd("s", datediff("s", AIn.TIME, AOut.TIME)-datediff("s", 0, MD.DefRest), 0)) AS DUROFWORK
  , IIF(cdate(AIn.[TIME]) > cdate(MD.DEFIN), format(dateadd("s", datediff("s", cdate(MD.DEFIN),
          cdate(AIn.[TIME])),0),"hh:nn:ss"),'') AS LATEIN
FROM ((ABSEN AS AIn 
       INNER JOIN MASTERDAYS AS MD ON AIn.LOCATION = MD.LOCATION) 
       INNER JOIN MASTERID AS MI ON MI.ID=AIn.ID)
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                  FROM ABSEN AS AOut1 
                  WHERE AOut1.INOUT='OUT') AS AOut ON (AOut.LOCATION=AIn.LOCATION) AND (AOut.DATE=AIn.DATE)           AND (AOut.ID=AIn.ID)
WHERE format(AIn.Date,"dddd")=MD.day
      AND  AIn.INOUT='IN' AND AIn.OPTION IS NULL AND AOut.OPTION IS NULL AND MI.POSITIONID='STAFF';


Is it always 1 IN and 0-1 OUT per day, per location? Is there also a 'person' involved?

You create records in Absen for non-attendance? Why does Absen show PRESENT for Sunday? Access reads 0 time as 12:00:00 AM.

@tinazmu , Is it always 1 IN and 0-1 OUT per day, per location? You're right per day always have 1 in and 1 out .Is there also a 'person' involved?  You mean definitely people are involved in and out in 1 day

So need to do calculations per person? Why does your sample data not reflect this?

@June7 , sorry that's a typo. Access reads 0 time as 12:00:00 AM. So what should I do?

@June7 So need to do calculations per person? Why does your sample data not reflect this? how can I calculate time with transform pivot sql please Guide ME

Options for dealing with 0 time; 1) leave field NULL; 2) don't create records for non-attendance; 3) IIf() calc to deal with (which you seem to do).

Why do you have 26-Aug against every row in your results?

@tinazmu ,  sorry that's a typo

If you can give up using TRANSFORM; then you can use something like:
SELECT 
    AIn.Date AS [DATE]
  , MD.day AS [Day of Week]
  , MI.NAMEID
  , AIn.status
  , IIF(AIn.STATUS = 'NOT PRESENT', '',MD.DEFREST) AS DEFREST
  , IIF(AIn.STATUS = 'NOT PRESENT', '',AIn.TIME) AS [IN]
  , IIF(AIn.STATUS = 'NOT PRESENT', '',AOut.TIME) AS OUT
  , IIF(AIn.STATUS = 'NOT PRESENT', '',
          dateadd("s", datediff("s", AIn.TIME, AOut.TIME)-datediff("s", 0, MD.DefRest), 0)) AS DUROFWORK
  , IIF(cdate(AIn.[TIME]) > cdate(MD.DEFIN), format(dateadd("s", datediff("s", cdate(MD.DEFIN),
          cdate(AIn.[TIME])),0),"hh:nn:ss"),'') AS LATEIN
FROM ((ABSEN AS AIn 
       INNER JOIN MASTERDAYS AS MD ON AIn.LOCATION = MD.LOCATION) 
       INNER JOIN MASTERID AS MI ON MI.ID=AIn.ID)
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                  FROM ABSEN AS AOut1 
                  WHERE AOut1.INOUT='OUT') AS AOut 
       ON (AOut.LOCATION=AIn.LOCATION) 
          AND (AOut.DATE=AIn.DATE)
          AND (AOut.ID=AIn.ID)
WHERE format(AIn.Date,"dddd")=MD.day
      AND  AIn.INOUT='IN';


I assumed that your 'other' table NAM
In my case I held the 'time-only' columns in 'ShortText' (you may need to adjust, if yours is different.


thanks for your answer but why you use hh:nn:ss not this hh:mm:ss

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/format-a-date-and-time-field-47fbbdc1-52fa-416a-b8d5-ba24d881b698

I want to ask you. for 1. I don't see the Days column in your answer query.Is it in this line code MD.day as [Day of Week], but it is from table MASTERDAYS and 2. Example from table Absen I have ID column then I want to innerjoin to the table MASTERID to take column MASTERID.NAMEID How should I adapt the code from your answer. Please Guide me

I tried this query and no records return.

You should tell us the datatypes you used

@dlaksmi, we have format(AIn.Date,"dddd")=MD.day in the where clause; so these are the same.

@June7, I stored times in text format (there is no 'time' datatype in Access but I could store them with '0' date part, I guess). I have tested it with the data OP posted -as displayed; I don't know why you don't get any rows; have you tried debugging it a bit: 'why wouldn't it return any rows'?

@dlaksmi, I updated it to include ID

@tinazmu , Thanks but ID not from table MASTERDAYS but another table MASTERID

I changed it again, assumed that you join MASTERID via MASTERID.ID. It would be far easier if you edited your question, and included these additional requirements with table DDL (ie how would we know how these tables are related?)

@tinazmu , Your answer update is perfect. If I have any questions, I will definitely ask you

@tinazmu , For others I managed to format succesfull but the line code didn't work FORMAT(AIn.Date,"dd-MMM-yy") AS [DATE] Result in report viewer 26-Aug-24 00:00:00 . Is there anything wrong with the format ?. AOut.Date Does this also have to be formatted if yes how

What is the data type of AIn.DATE? What is your reporting tool? if AIn.Date is in text; the FORMAT function was useless; and it appears that your reporting tool reads/maps it into a DATE&TIME field and formats it  26-Aug-24 00:00:00; you need to map it to a text/char field.

@tinazmu , sorry I was late replying. What is the data type of AIn.DATE?  it is Public Property [DATE] As DateTime . What is your reporting tool? it is Report viewer/Rdlc` Problem Solved So I set the expression in the report viewer

@tinazmu , link I have another post that has not been solved maybe you can help me

@tinazmu , It would be far easier if you edited your question, and included these additional requirements with table DDL (ie how would we know how these tables are related?) This is you right there is a problem with the ID so I updated in the post

@tinazmu , Update testing table as on 29-08-2024 I have updated in the post, Please Solution from you

@tinazmu , Problem solved, I may have missed an update from your answer. For this line AND (AOut.ID=AIn.ID)

Using TRANSFORM (PIVOT) I think will have to do a subsequent query for difference calcs.
Access reads 0 time as 12:00:00 AM. I deleted time data from Sunday records to simplify.
Consider this approach:
SELECT Absen.Date, Absen.Status, Absen.Location, MasterDays.Day, MasterDays.Defin, 
MasterDays.Defrest, Max(IIf([InOut]="IN",[Time])) AS [IN], 
Max(IIf([InOut]="OUT",[Time])) AS Out, 
Format([OUT]-[IN]-Defrest,"hh:mm:ss") AS DurOfWork, 
Format([IN]-Defin, "hh:mm:ss") AS LateIn
FROM MasterDays INNER JOIN Absen ON MasterDays.Location = Absen.Location
AND (MASTERDAYS.DAY = FORMAT(ABSEN.DATE,'dddd'))
GROUP BY Absen.Date, Absen.Status, Absen.Location, MasterDays.Day, MasterDays.Defin, MasterDays.Defrest;


thanks for your answer, Your answer is very simple but why the result DurOfWork and LateIn #error

I did not get #error in my test.

for column TIME I use type data Text / String

Why? I used Date/Time type.

does it matter if I use a string type and perhap function like that datediff or another

for record easier I can put 0 in the in and out column. Please Guide me

String will have to be converted to date/time value in calc. DateDiff() will do implicit conversion.

please guide me, I have also updated the data type in the post to make it easier
